# Using Graphviz / yed to produce a timeline + graph

Tags: graphviz

I had an idea of representing something like a family tree where nodes are connected by directed graphs but to add an additional dimension of time on the y-axis. So imagine the top of the page representing 1900 and all the way down to the bottom being 2020.

[image]

Is there a way to do something like this in Graphviz or yed? Basically auto layout a specified digraph but the position of nodes on the y axis is linked to time?

Answer (score 8):

Here is shells.gv - part of the source:

```
digraph shells {
    size="7,8";
    node [fontsize=24, shape = plaintext];

    1972 -> 1976;
    1976 -> 1978;
    1978 -> 1980;
    1980 -> 1982;
    1982 -> 1984;
    1984 -> 1986;
    1986 -> 1988;
    1988 -> 1990;
    1990 -> future;

    node [fontsize=20, shape = box];
    { rank=same;  1976 Mashey Bourne; }
    { rank=same;  1978 Formshell csh; }
    { rank=same;  1980 esh vsh; }
    { rank=same;  1982 ksh "System-V"; }
    { rank=same;  1984 v9sh tcsh; }
    { rank=same;  1986 "ksh-i"; }
    { rank=same;  1988 KornShell Perl rc; }
    { rank=same;  1990 tcl Bash; }
    { rank=same;  "future" POSIX "ksh-POSIX"; }

    Thompson -> Mashey;
    Thompson -> Bourne;
    Thompson -> csh;
    csh -> tcsh;
    Bourne -> ksh;
    Bourne -> esh;
    Bourne -> vsh;
    Bourne -> "System-V";
    Bourne -> v9sh;
    v9sh -> rc;
    Bourne -> Bash;
    "ksh-i" -> Bash;
    KornShell -> Bash;
    esh -> ksh;
    vsh -> ksh;
    Formshell -> ksh;
    csh -> ksh;
    KornShell -> POSIX;
    "System-V" -> POSIX;
    ksh -> "ksh-i";
    "ksh-i" -> KornShell;
    KornShell -> "ksh-POSIX";
    Bourne -> Formshell;

    edge [style=invis];
    1984 -> v9sh -> tcsh ;
    1988 -> rc -> KornShell;
    Formshell -> csh;
    KornShell -> Perl;
}
```

Producing this:
[image]

Comment: Excellent! This produces almost exactly what I wanted. One quick question: I see you use the rank property to maintain horizontal alignment but then towards the end I see some use of invisible edges? Is this both for the same purpose?

Comment: A related question I posted: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74288/tool-library-to-visualize-network-graph-timeline-graphviz-yed-like

Comment: I can not take credit for this graph, I just knew where to find it.  I think the invisible edges are to help manage the node placement within the subgraphs.  Comment them out and see what changes

Comment: That's fine. Credit is due for kowing where  to look! :)

Answer (score 4):

The graph you want in Graphviz is pretty straightforward, you just switch on the `dir=TD`, separate your nodes into subgraphs and use `rank=same` inside them to force them be on the same level.

The tricky part may be with achieving the `Z` node on your example. You can do it using HTML-like tables in the label. Full graphviz interpretation of your example picture will look like this:

```
digraph  {
    node [shape=rect style=filled fillcolor="#d2deee" fontname="Arial"]
    edge [color="#658bb2"]
    dir = TD
    1900 -> 1950 -> 2020 [style=invis]
    subgraph 1900 {
        rank=same
        1900 [
            fillcolor="#efefef"
            fontcolor="#182697"
            fontname="Arial bold"
        ]
        A
    }
    subgraph 1950 {
        rank=same
        1950 [
            fillcolor="#efefef"
            fontcolor="#182697"
            fontname="Arial bold"
        ]
        B
    }
    subgraph 2020 {
        rank=same
        2020 [
            fillcolor="#efefef"
            fontcolor="#182697"
            fontname="Arial bold"
        ]
        C
    }
    Z [
        shape=plain
        label=<
            <table cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td cellpadding="15" border="0" width="70" port="p1"></td>
                    <td border="0">Z</td>
                    <td cellpadding="15" border="0" width="70" port="p2"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        >
    ]
    A -> Z:p1
    B -> Z:p2
    Z -> C
    C
}
```

which will render you:

[image: result]

Comment: I'm confused by the HTML use -- does graphviz natively understand some HTML subset? Or is this a trick that only works when using an HTML output format?

Comment: @JosephGarvin Graphviz supports a few HTML tags in labels, the most important of them being <table> tag. In the past frontend developers could build a whole website on tables, it's a very powerful layout tool. And while it makes graphviz code look a bit weird, as you rightfully pointed out, it gives you the flexibility graphviz missed before. And yes, it is supported for any output format.
More info in the docs: https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html

Answer (score 2):

**The invisible nodes control left to right ordering**

Just to clarify the `edge [style=invis];` invisible nodes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61552544/895245 , if we remove them we get:

[image]

so we see that e.g. Graphviz decided to place Formshell comes after csh. If we restore the:

```
    Formshell -> csh;
```

line, then we get Formshell before csh:

[image]

The graph author appears to have selected those in order to make the graph look more compact horizontally.

Tested in Graphviz 2.42.2.